# How to call MySQL Stored Procedure from Tableau

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, tableau-api

We are migrating our Reporting solution from SSRS-MSSQL to Tableau-MySQL but recently I came to know that Tableau doesn't support calling MySQL Stored Procedure.
I have heard there is a work around people have found to do so but I couldn't find any.
Can anybody please help me with it.
And yeah I also need to pass Paramaters to the Stored Procedure.

Comment: Can you post the code of what the stored procedure needs to do? Perhaps that code could be translated into a nested subquery.

Comment: And often another option to a nested subquery is a Tableau Level of Detail (LOD) calculation

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a function that calls a stored procedure in MYSQL and call that function using select DB.fun_name() in custom query,click preview results if it updates your DB then it is working if it is not then there is no other way that I know of.